# How can I change number of channels on Resnet to make it work only on B/W images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I'm working on tensorflow and my dataset is composed only by Black and White images, so I thought that I could make my neural net (currently I am using Resnet50) less heavy and easier to train and test by changing the number of channels from 3 to 1,
Is there a way to do so?
(Ik I can treat b/w images as rgb images but I don't want to do that)

Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/ResNet50, you can specify the input tensor. Have you tried supplying one with size 1 at axis 2, e.g. (300, 300, 1)?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem: color has three channels; B&W has only one.  In your input flow, simply change the 3-channel specifications to 1: wherever you see a dimension size of 3, change it to 1.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan the docs you have shared clearly state that: `It should have exactly 3 inputs channels...`  So I don't think this is possible

Comment: @Yatin to be honest, that only applies to *input_shape*, not *input_tensor*. It is worth a try, you never know.

Comment: thanks for the answers, I tried the following now:
`model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,input_tensor=tf.constant([img_width, img_height, 1]) )`
and it gave me error:
` You should not pass an EagerTensor to `Input`. '
ValueError: You should not pass an EagerTensor to `Input`. For example, instead of creating an InputLayer, you should instantiate your model and directly call it on your input.`

Answer (score 0):

The pretrained weights in keras.applications require a 3 channel input. You could one of two things:

1. Use a different pretrained model that works on grayscale images.
2. Set the R, G and B channels to replicate your BW input, then fine-tune the entire neural network on your own dataset. This probably won't work without the fine-tuning step.

On a side note, I must say this task will not help in your goal of making it 'less heavy and easier to train and test'. If you call `model.summary()` on keras Resnet50, you see that of the total trainable 23,534,592 parameters, only about 10K of them are in the initial layer. So at best you can reduce the number of parameters by an insignificant few thousand.

I would instead suggest using a lighter model such as MobileNet that are also available in Keras.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am already reading my image as rgb but I would have liked to exploit the b/w nature of my image to reduce the size of my network but apparently it's not possible (or not so immediate) I also tried copy pasting the source code of resnet and editing but it wasn't working and I was looking for a more convenient way to change the number of channels in my net, I don't know if I could change to MobileNet, I'd like to have the best accuracy possible and idk if I can reach that also with MobileNet